# $U + W$ is the intersection of all vector subspaces in $V$ containing $U \cup W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U, W$ be two vector space $V$. Denote by $$U + W = \{u + w : u \in U, w \in W\}$$to be the set of all vectors in $V$ that can be written as $u + w$ with $u \in U$ and $w \in W$. How do I see that $U + W$ is the intersection of all vector subspaces in $V$ containing $U \cup W$?

Answer (score 1):

1) Show that $U+V$ is *a* vector space containing $U$ and containing $V$.
2) Take any vector space $W$ with $U\cap V\subseteq W$, and show that $U+V\subseteq W$.

That is the meaning of the exercise. Now, to achieve each of those, proceed slowly by being explicit about what you need to show. For instance, for 1): Let $x\in U$. You need to show that $x\in U+V$. Can you do that? Similarly, for 2): Let $x\in U+V$. You need to show that $x\in W$. Well, $x=u+v$ for some $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, right? Can you conclude that $u\in W$? that $v\in W$? that $u+v\in W$?

Answer (score 0):

$U,W$ are subspaces and contained in $U+W$. Conversely, any subspace of $V$ containing $U,W$ must also contain $U+W$ (since they are close under sum operation). Thus $U+W$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $U,W$ which is another way of saying the intersection of all subspaces in $V$ containing  $U\cup W$.